# Match sequences of n-tuples

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My following C# code returns the following:

`{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s,t),(u,v,y)}`

`{(a,b),(c,d,e)}`

`{(a,b),(c,d)}`

But I don't want `{(a,b),(c,d,e)}` to be matched since the tuples inside are of different orders (2 and 3 respectively).

```
private void testwest()
{
    string st = "abc+{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s+1,t),(u,v,y)}+test-{(a,b),(c,d,e)}+rst+{(a,b),(c,d)}";
    Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"{(\(.*?\),\(.*?\))}");

    foreach (Match mt in oRegex.Matches(st))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I should have mentioned that the elements of n-tuple can be any text not containing comma. I've edited the above example string as shown in bold below:
abc+{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,**s+1**,t),(u,v,y)}+test-{(a,b),(c,d,e)}+rst+{(a,b),(c,d)}

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the rule you're trying to express with a C# regular expression does not fall into the category of regular expressions in formal language theory. Therefore I don't think it's possible to reach your goal using single C# regular expression pattern, but I'm not 100% sure of that, because as far as I know C# regular expression processing does not strictly follow the formal language theory definitions. I believe though you're going to need some extra processing, e.g. what @Shar1er80 proposed in his answer.

Comment: Do you want to go up to N order tuples or do you have a limit ?

Comment: @Bongo The tuples would be of any order >1. The max order will be just a reasonable number, say, 10. So, a sequence to match should have either 2-tuples, or a 3-tuples,......., or 9-tuples etc. and not the mixture of these tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to evaluate the tuples inside the `foreach` to see if they're all the same length before you decide to output the results.

Give this a try:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string st = "abc+{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s+1,t),(u,v,y)}+test-{(a,b),(c,d,e)}+rst+{(a,b),(c,d)}";
        Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"{(\(.*?\),\(.*?\))}");
        foreach (Match mt in oRegex.Matches(st))
        {
            MatchCollection mCol = Regex.Matches(mt.Value, "\\([^)]+\\)");
            int tupleCount = mCol[0].Value.Split(',').Length;
            if (mCol.Count == mCol.Cast<Match>()
                .Where(m => m.Value.Split(',').Length == tupleCount).Count())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once inside the `foreach`, we perform another `Regex.Matches()` to get the tuples.  We then perform `Linq` on the `MatchCollection` to remove tuples that don't have the same of tuples as the first.  This will return a temporary `IEnumerable` whose `Count()` we can compare to the `MatchCollection.Count`.  If they match, display the `Match`.

Results:

```
{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s+1,t),(u,v,y)}
{(a,b),(c,d)}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/27M52o)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I should have mentioned that the elements of an n-tuple can be any text not containing comma. I've edited my original post. In that case your m.Length part will not work. Moreover, I noticed that your first RegEx captures any substring enclosed by {...}. For instance, your RegEx would capture {test} as well in "abc+{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s,t),(u,v,y)}+c+{test}-d+{(a,b),(c,d,e)}+rst+{(a,b),(c,d)}"

Comment: @nam The logic is not far from what you're asking. I'll update my answer later

Comment: @nam See updated answer.  It counts the amount of items that are in the tuple and compares that, instead of the length of the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't possible to do this solely with regex.
This code works with your input.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string st = "abc+{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s,t),(u,v,y)}+test-{(a,b),(c,d,e)}+rst+{(a,b),(c,d)}";
        int possibleCountTuple = st.Length / 2;
        for(int i = 1; i<possibleCountTuple; i++)
        {
            TestStringForTuple(st,i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TestStringForTuple(string str,int order)
    {
        Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"{((.{"+order+"}),(.{"+order+"}))}");
        foreach (Match mt in oRegex.Matches(str))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);
        }
    }
```

n{order}Matches any string that contains a sequence of order n's.
I don't know if this is what you are looking for but it does work.

The possibleCountTuple is only an approximation and I know that this isn't nearly correct but I think you know how to handle it

Comment: I have added an Edit at the end of my original post. The elements of an n-tuple can contain any text not containing comma.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the order of the first element before matching the rest.

```
private void testwest()
{
    string st = "abc+{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s+1,t),(u,v,y)}+test-{(a,b),(c,d,e)}+rst+{(a,b),(c,d)}";
    Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"{(\([^)]*\)(,\([^)]*\))*)}");

    foreach (Match mt in oRegex.Matches(st))
    {
        int order = mt.Value
            .TakeWhile(ch => ch != ')')
            .Count(ch => ch == ',') + 1;
        var tuplePattern = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat("[^,)]+", order));
        if (Regex.IsMatch(mt.Value, "{\(" + tuplePattern + "\)(,\("+ tuplePattern +"\))*}"))
        {
             Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code matches {(a,b),(c,d)} only and not the {(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s+1,t),(u,v,y)} .This is probably since your first Regex is considering only the single character elements in the n-tuple. Please see my EDIT in my original post.

Comment: The first Regex was only matching collections of exactly two tuples, I've fixed that so it matches 1+.